# is there a way to optimize a sql request with a lot of "AND"

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization, query-optimization

I just wrote this request which works:

```
select assets.name 
from assets,
     users 
where assets.user_id = users.id 
  and users.id = '98d7f61e-af36-48ae-b28b-c233fa78fe3a' 
  and users.account_status = 'APPROVED' 
  and assets.for_sale = TRUE
```

I'm asking to myself if it is possible to optimize my request with using a special structure instead these four "AND" instructions.

Comment: You can write it in different ways, but they are not really more optimized in terms of performance.

Comment: I'd prefer to use join syntax for the first condition, just for clarity. I don't think it affects the query plan.

Comment: The special structure to consider is called an index.  An index on assets (user_id, for_sale, name), and an index on users (id, account_status) could be helpful.

Comment: The query is simple enough that there's not much space left for optimisation on its end. If you have control over the schema, you can make sure the table is appropriately [indexed](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-createindex.html) or even [clustered](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-cluster.html). You can also build [materialized views](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-creatematerializedview.html) for frequently executed queries on infrequently changing data.

Comment: thanks to all of you

Comment: To echo @GertArnold, that join syntax was superceded by ANSI SQL JOIN syntax decades ago and is not considered good practice

Comment: What are you trying to optimize? If it's legibility - ANSI join syntax. If it's performance, we need a query plan and schema. If it's comprehensibility - materialized views?

Comment: The query looks good enough. With the proper indexes, it should run fast.